# OpenCV Убрать полосы на черно-белом изображении

Tags: python, opencv

Подскажите, как можно убрать полосы на черно-белых изображениях, таких как:
[image: Ладья]

Задача стоит по изображению определить тип фигуры (черная ладья, белый ферзь и .д.). Сравниваю изображения через SSIM и PSNR. Полосы сильно влияют на эти значения.

Comment: Сейчас пытаюсь работать с через:

blurred = cv2.blur(gray, (1, 1))
(_, thresh) = cv2.threshold(255-blurred, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

но при таком подходе или фигура начинает исчезать или полоса остается.